# "What's the best thing about planet Earth?"

Tags: dialogue, dc-extended-universe, justice-league

At the very beginning of the movie, *Justice League* (2017), two kids record a video with Superman for their podcast. One of the kids asks:

> "What's the best thing about planet Earth?"

Just as Superman smiles and begins to answer it, the footage just cuts.

Is the question answered anywhere else in the movie, by Superman or by anyone else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is **not** answered by Superman **during the movie** or anyone else in that matter, but Henry Cavill (the person who played Superman) has said (according to [LA Times](http://www.latimes.com/entertainment/movies/la-et-mn-superman-justice-league-henry-cavill-20171119-story.html))

> “I think — and I imagine Superman would also think — ,”

he says of the possible reply,

> “the greatest quality of people and humankind is their capacity to love regardless of hardship or difficulties or personal trials. People can be living in the most horrendous war zone or under the most incredible oppression and yet they can still love so selflessly and so unconditionally — and still bear hope through that love. It’s amazing to see what people can do. I think Superman would recognize that and appreciate it.”

Comment: So, the indirect answer to the question would be, " the people of Earth"?

Comment: Technically yes but its more to do with human relationship with each other through "hardships". Note that this is only what Cavill thinks is what Superman would say if he had the chance to reply. Technically there is no proper answer to your question because its impossible to tell.

Comment: I mean I literally can't add anything more because only Henry Cavill comments on it and no one else does...